# How to use ILIKE in postgres with two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns which are called surname and name.

For example I have 3 users

```
Zuckerberg Mark
Gates Bill
Jobs Steve
```

If my input is only one phrase such as "Ma" or "Mark" or "Gate" etc. my query works well, but if i enter and surname and name I got an empty result

```
select
       u.surname,
       u.name,
       u.avatar
from users u
where (surname ilike '%Mark Zuckerberg%' or name ilike '%Mark Zuckerberg%')
order by surname, name
```

How can I rebuild my query for this goal?

Comment: Your example data only shows one column, but your table seems to have three columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry my previous answer had a typo, but this works:

```
select
       u.surname,
       u.name,
       u.avatar
from users u
where ((u.surname ||' '|| u.name) ilike '%Mark Zuckerberg%' or (u.name ||' '||u.surname) ilike '%Mark Zuckerberg%')
order by surname, name
```

Here's a sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4e6ce/7